# Loopback where do I see all access tokens in datasource?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

After an user logins, an access token will be created and stored in datasource, right? Why I'm not seeing any records?
I am using mongodb compass. Am I missing anything?

Comment: can you share your user-model.js please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your `model-config.json` and `datasources.json` files.

The `model-config.json` file should have something like this:

```
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
```

This dictates which datasource your AccessTokens are stored. As you can see, mine are stored in datasource `db`.

Then go to your `datasources.json` and find the corresponding datasource, mine is as such:

```
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
```

That will show you where your access tokens are being stored. As you can see, mine are stored in memory.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!